# Finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for a boundary problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the boundary problem be: $x^2y''+\lambda y=0$ with $1<x<2$ and boundary conditions $y(1) = 0 = y(2)$. Assume $\lambda = \mu^2>0$I am trying to solve for $r$ by first dividing $x^2y''+\lambda y=0$ by $x^2$ to get $y''+ \frac{\lambda}{x^2} y =0$. This will give me $r = \pm i \frac{\mu}{x}$.

However, this will give me $y(x) = C_1\cos(\mu)+C_2\sin(\mu)$. I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here because it seems like the $x$ terms just cancel out unless I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Cauchy-Euler equation, so we assume $y=x^r.$ Then we have $y'=rx^{r-1}$ and $y''=r(r-1)x^{r-2},$ which we insert into the original DE as
\begin{align*}
r(r-1)x^r+\lambda x^r&=0\\
r^2-r+\lambda&=0\\
r&=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4\lambda}}{2}.
\end{align*}
Let
\begin{align*}
r_+&=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda}}{2}\\
r_-&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda}}{2}.
\end{align*}
Then 
$$y=c_+ x^{r_+}+c_- x^{r_-}. $$
The boundary conditions yield
\begin{align*}
0&=c_+ +c_- \\
0&=c_+ 2^{r_+}+c_- 2^{r_-}.
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, the only solution is the trivial solution $c_-=c_+=0,$ implying that there are no solutions to this eigenvalue problem (since eigenvectors are nonzero by definition).

Answer (score 0):

Since $y$ is, in general, a function of $x$, we will first need to convert the equation into an equation with constant coefficients so that your  method can be applied. Notice that this can be done by replacing $x$ by $e^{z}$, where since $1 < x < 2$, we have $0 < z < \ln 2$.

Also, if we denote $D \equiv \dfrac{d}{dx}$ and $\theta \equiv \dfrac{d}{dz}$, then

$$x^2 y'' = \theta \left( \theta - 1 \right) y$$

Hence, we get the boundary value problem

$$\theta^2 y - \theta y + \lambda y = 0, \ 0 < z < \ln 2$$

and the boundary conditions $y \left( 0 \right) = y \left( \ln 2 \right) = 1$.

Now, you can proceed by your method to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for the BVP. However, in the end, do not forget to replace $z$ by suitable function of $x$, so that the solution is in terms of what was given in the problem statement.